# Negative binomial and joint probability distribution

Tags: probability

> An urn contains $w$ white and $b$ black balls. I made some extractions with replacement and $X_a$ is the random variable representing the number of extraction made to get the $a^\mathrm{th}$ white ball. I need to find joint probability distribution for $\Pr(X_a=s,X_b=t)$, where $b>a$ and $t>s$.

I know this is a negative binomial distribution with probability function:

$$\Pr(X_a=i)=\binom{i-1}{a-1}{p_w}^a(1-p_w)^{i-a}$$

How do I combine this to get $\Pr(X_a=s,X_b=t)$?

Comment: What does "$th$" mean, in the definition of $X_a$? Did you mean "$a^\mathrm{th}$" ?

Comment: I meant the first or second or third or $a-th$.

Comment: Are you using $b$ to mean two different things?  You probably want $\Pr(X_a=s,X_b=t) = \Pr(X_a=s)\Pr(X_{b-a}=t-s)$

Comment: I didn't know that also the negative binomial was ["Memorylessness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#Discrete_memorylessness), thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the problem has no memory, so $\mathrm{Pr}(X_{a+r}=s+q\mid X_a=s)=\mathrm{Pr}(X_r=q)$.

Then, since $b>a$, $$\mathrm{Pr}(X_a=s, X_b=t)=\mathrm{Pr}(X_a=s)\mathrm{Pr}(X_b=t\mid X_a=s)=\\=\mathrm{Pr}(X_a=s)\mathrm{Pr}(X_{b-a}=t-s)$$

Which you can easily calculate.

Comment: I didn't know that also the negative binomial was ["Memorylessness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorylessness#Discrete_memorylessness), thanks.

Comment: +1) @Paul Make it a custom to accept answers if they are acceptable. You received about $10$ answers on questions, but accepted none of them. Why not?

Comment: @drhab sorry, didn't know that :-)

Comment: @Paul Ego te absolvo. You also accepted a good custom :).